# error "transaction which cannot be processed" when deploying contract

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am working on application which allow user to deploy contracts (ERC20 and NFT). Frontend application is holding abi and bytecode and during deployment only constructor parameters are injected from UI. When app is using metamask on wallet-connect with other wallets than gnosis, transaction can be signed and everything is ok. When i am using gnosis as a wallet (iframe) or wallet-connect through gnosis, when i am requesting wallet to sign transaction i am getting this UI modal on gnosis (there is no info in console):

`This Safe App initiated a transaction which cannot be processed. Please get in touch with the developer of this Safe App for more information.`

[image]

Also i wanted to notice that when I am signing transactions on already deployed contracts, gnosis is working okay, only deploy transactions raises this error.

For signing transactions I am using `ethersjs` and `web3-onboard` with `gnosisModule()`

```
  // wallet is from "@web3-onboard/react"
  const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(wallet.provider);
  const signer = web3Provider.getSigner();
  const factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer);
  const contract = await factory.deploy( ... , { value });
  await contract.deployed();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Safe App functionality doesn't support deployment transactions at the moment